# Is there a way to mask the area projected in QGIS 3D View?

Tags: qgis, 3d, 3d-map

I'm attemping to create a 3D map view for export to a PDF.  However, QGIS's 3D map view seems to base its canvas solely on the viewable area within the main window in QGIS proper.  e.g., as you zoom in and out of your 2D map, this adjusts what the 3D map will project.

The problem here is that I have a lot of data that is strung along a fairly narrow corridor, so I have a lot of "wasted" canvas on either side that I do not need in my 3D view.  Is there any way to restrict the area projected in the 3D view, other than adjusting my zoom in the 2D view?  I can't zoom in any further without losing data off the top and bottom of the canvas, and I can't export this current view because there is far too much empty canvas to the left and right.